# What is the meaning of this rebus?

Tags: rebus

Here is a rebus:

[image: The Rebus]

Can you guess what it is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Buh bah, nothing obvious springs to mind. Maybe

> screenplays (movie writing) or "screen plays" (American hand-egg tactics)?

Comment: Amazing! You got it right.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be

> [on-screen controls](http://101.wacom.com/UserHelp/en/OSC.htm), since it shows a controller on a screen.

Comment: I'm afraid not the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's a

> TV Controller (a remote controller)

This may also be too obvious but,

> A controller inside of a tv screen.

Comment: Good thinking too. But no, that's not the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer might be

> Computer Game

But that might be too obvious.

> The screen looks like a computer screen + a playstation controller representing 'game'

Comment: Good thinking but I'm afraid the answer is not that obvious.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be:

> Comptroller as you are mixing a computer and a controller.

Side thoughts:

> Computer being a loose term as this is really a representation of a monitor/tv screen. However it could be represented as a computer due to the all-in-one computers.